# How to swap two strings?

Tags: arrays, vb.net, swap, xor

I have **two** variables I want to **switch** which are **strings**. 
They contain and **first** and **second** name.

I wanted to switch them using the `least possible amount of lines` so that's why I haven't created a **third** variable.

I tried using a `xor swap` but an error message says James Adams can't be converted to type `long`.

Is `xor` only for **integers**, if so how do I swap the variables **efficiently**? Thanks, any ideas appreciated. I'll add the code if that's helpful.

**Plutonix** has suggested `names = names.OrderBy(Function(o) o).ToArray()` which works. Thanks. Can anyone explain how it does because I haven't seen this before?

```
For counter1 = 0 to 5
   For counter2 = counter1 + 1 to 5
       If names(counter1) >                      names(counter2) then

           names = names.OrderBy(Function(o) o).ToArray()
       End if 
   Next 
Next
```

Please excuse formatting issues or blame Apple.

Comment: consider adding your codes.

Comment: what makes you think a third variable is inefficient?

Comment: you are concerned about the lines used or memory use? the latter wouldnt make difference since any other way will have to use some kind of variable, one way or the other. As far as lines is concerned, i dont find any problem having 3 lines to do what you want. Xor is a bitwise operation, 0Xor1=1, 1Xor1=0....

Comment: Here's a one-liner: `Dim a = "a" : Dim b = "b" : Dim t = a : a = b : b = t`

Comment: since they are in 2 vars, why do you have to swap them at all?  Just use them in a different order when you need to.  *The real problem is that programmers have spent far too much time worrying about efficiency in the wrong places and at the wrong times* - Knuth.  See also [Micro-Optimization and Meatballs](http://blog.codinghorror.com/micro-optimization-and-meatballs/)

Comment: Btw, why did you tag your question `arrays`?

Comment: I need to swap them as I'm using a sorting algorithm. I tagged arrays because it is in an array which you can see if you guys want me to show the code

Comment: I was tasked with finding the shortest way and im new to programming. I probably shouldn't have used the words less efficient. What do you mean "adding your codes"?

Comment: shortest for sorting (the X, not the Y problem): `myArray = myArray.OrderBy(Function(o) o).ToArray()`

Comment: How does that work @plutonix? Btw thanks to whoever suggested question improvements

Comment: For the record, Plutonix **did not** suggest you need to invoke it in any loops.  One line is all you need to sort the whole array..

Answer (score 0):

The "xor swap trick" is defined on integral types. A string is not an integral type, but rather a sequence of such a type.

http://graphics.stanford.edu/~seander/bithacks.html#SwappingValuesXOR

Consider using a temporary variable instead.

Comment: So is there an alternative for strings

Comment: @John.R, if you have two character sequences of equal length, you could xor-swap each character pair at every index.

Comment: They're names of different lengths

Comment: For strings of different lengths, you must pad the shortest to the length of the largest. The pad character is application-specific, but probably a space-character or null-character.

Comment: Thanks for the help but im very new to coding (doing it in IT class) so these things go over my head. This seems to work: myArray = myArray.OrderBy(Function(o) o).ToArray()

Comment: @John.R, without seeing more code, I really don't. Sorry about that.